# Variable returns 0 when inside loop

Tags: php, variables, static

I am writing a simple PHP class, but when I am trying to use a variable inside of a foreach loop, it is printing out 0 (null). But, when I echo it out right before that loop, it prints the correct value. Any thoughts?

```
class Search
{
    public static $KeyObject=null;

    //...KeyObject is assigned some value...


    public function resultsToHTML()
    {
        $KeyObject = $this->KeyObject;
        echo "inResults: $KeyObject <br />";
        $htmlString = "";
        if(!empty($this->resultList))
        {
            $htmlString .= "<table><th>Results</th><tbody>";
            foreach($this->resultList as $row)
            {
                $htmlString .= "<tr><td>"+$KeyObject+"</td></tr>";
                $htmlString .= "<tr>";
                foreach($row as $key => $value)
                {
                    $htmlString .= "<td class=\"$key\" id=\"$value\">$value</td>";
                }
                $htmlString .= "</tr>";
            }
            $htmlString .= "</tbody></table>";
        }

        return $htmlString;
    }
}
```

This returns...

> inResults: Player 
>   00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: 0 and null are not the same thing in PHP.

Comment: you might mean zero instead of null in your question.

Comment: `$htmlString .= "<tr><td>"+$KeyObject+"</td></tr>";`  => `$htmlString .= '0';`. Use a `.`, not `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you're using `+` instead of `.` for concatenation.

```
$htmlString .= "<tr><td>"+$KeyObject+"</td></tr>";
```

Replace the `+` with a `.`:

```
$htmlString .= "<tr><td>".$KeyObject."</td></tr>";
```

`+` will [juggle your strings into integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) (returning 0) and concatenate that zero to the rest of your string through the totally valid `$htmlString += [string here]`.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!! Too much switching between JavaScript and PHP :p